# jQuery - Off() not working depending of the event

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, selector

I'm using the "off event" to avoid multiple AJAX requests (if the user do multiple clicks, for example). Works perfectly.

The problem is, depending on how "on('click')" event is called, the event off() simply doesn't work. I will give an example:

**Function:**

```
var addComment(elem) = function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../../ajax/request.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function(){
           // after this line, click the elem doesn't do anything
           elem.off('click');
        },
        success: function(result){
            if (result.success){
               console.log('success!');
            }else{
               console.log('no success...');
            }
            //making "elem" clickable again
            elem.on('click',function(){
                addComment(elem);
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert("Error Status: " + xhr.status + " Thrown Errors: "+thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

**Events:**

```
// Using this, the off event works normally
$('.divArea button.newComment').on('click',function(){
    addComment($(this));
});

// Using this, the off event simply is not executed
$('.divArea')
    .on('click', 'button.newComment',function(){
        addComment($(this));
    })
```

Why in the second case, off() doesn't work and what i should do to off() works properly in both event calling examples?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Your function definition syntax is wrong, how is that code running at all?

Comment: It should be `var addComment = function(elem) { ... }` or `function addComment(elem) { ... }`

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to disable the button when clicked and re-enable after ajax return?

Comment: @barman, it's actually wrong. I modified it when i was writting here in stackoverflow. Ignore the sintax errors, sorry.

Comment: @psalmody, it's a solution, but i choose off() because i think it's more secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the second version doesn't work is because when you use delegation, the event binding is not on the button, it's on actually `.divArea`. Delegation works by having the handler automatically check whether the target of the event matches the selector that you delegated to -- that's how it's able to extend to elements that didn't exist at the time the binding was established.

Since there are no bindings on individual elements, you can't remove them with `.off`.

What you can do is delegate to a selector with a class, and change the class when you handle the event.

```
$('.divArea').on('click', 'button.newComment:not(.handled)', function() {
    addComment($(this));
});

function addComment(elem) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../../ajax/request.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function(){
           // after this line, click the elem doesn't do anything
           elem.addClass("handled");
        },
        success: function(result){
            if (result.success){
               console.log('success!');
            }else{
               console.log('no success...');
            }
            //making "elem" clickable again
            elem.removeClass("handled");
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert("Error Status: " + xhr.status + " Thrown Errors: "+thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So basically, there is no away to "off" an element directly using the second event example? If there NO WAY to off the element, i would just use the first example, since it's fit perfectly. Btw, thank you very much for your answer. I didn't find an explanation why off() failed when i googled it.

Comment: Usually you use the second version because you're creating the elements dynamically. The first version won't work with dynamically-added elements.